# Writing browser specific hack in Less (for <IE9)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, less

I want to do something like this (Source - [CSS Tricks Article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/)):

```css
#veinte { color/*\**/: blue\9; }
```

in Less for IE7 and IE8 but it gives errors.

The below works:

```css
#diecinueve { color: blue\9; }
```

but there are some elements that I dont want to be called in IE9. e.g. I have something in IE9 with `:before` elements but because IE8 doesnt support it, I want to give it a `padding` only in IE8.

But this

```css
#veinte { color/*\**/: blue\9; }
```

gives errors in Less. I tried this

```css
#veinte { color~"/*\**/": blue\9; }
```

but that also doesnt work. Does anyone know how to do this in Less?

Comment: Do the CSS hacks provide what you need? Or is it just that the LESS compiler gives you errors?

Comment: To my knowledge, it cannot be done in LESS. The compiler does not allow either the `*` or the `\` or `/` in the property name. It also does not, to my knowledge, have a way of escaping an entire string _that **includes** the property name itself_.

Comment: Don't think you would still be looking for an answer to this one mate but judging by the no. of views this question has got I felt an updated answer would be helpful, so added one.

Answer (score 4):

[**Property name interpolation**](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-properties) is possible with Less v1.6.0 and above. Hence this hack can be implemented as shown below:

```
@hack: ~"/*\**/";
#veinte { 
    color@{hack}: blue\9; 
}
```

**Compiled CSS:**

```
#veinte {
    color/*\**/: blue\9;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you including [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) or another shiv script that adds classes directly to the `HTML` element?

Thus something like this:

```
.selector {  
  ...rules...  

  .lte8 & {  
    ... < IE9 styles ...  
  }  
}
```

Might suit your needs. (see: [nesting selectors](http://lesscss.org/#-nested-rules), [using the &](http://lesscss.org/#-advanced-usage-of-&))

Otherwise, since you're being hacky anyway, why not just reference a different .less compiled output sheet in a [conditional comment](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one: `background-position:~"-150px 0px\9" width:~"300px\9";`

example:

```
.test{
    width:~"300px\9";
}
```