# How to apply IE Fixes for LESS CSS

Tags: css, html-parsing, less

how to use ie 9 hack in less css?

ie 9 hack \0/

compiler  error

Following characters are exceptions and not encoded: ,, /, ?, @, &, +, ', ~, ! and $.

how to encode this characters ?

Comment: Don't use CSS hacks. Use Modernizr or conditional comments to add a class to the `<html>` element so that you can style it normally.

Comment: possible duplicate of [browser specific hack in less.css <ie9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464530/browser-specific-hack-in-less-css-ie9)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot... either use Modernizr like @Blender suggested or in your markup append ie9 class using:

```
<!--[if IE 9]><script>document.documentElement.className += " ie9";</script><![endif]-->
```

and use ie9 specific rules in LESS:

```
.ie9 & { /* IE9 rules */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply some hacks css with this following answer : [Writing browser specific hack in Less (for <IE9)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464530/writing-browser-specific-hack-in-less-for-ie9)

```
@hack: ~"/*\**/";
#veinte { 
    color@{hack}: blue\9; 
}
```

Compiled CSS:

```
#veinte {
    color/*\**/: blue\9;
}
```